# Ruby as a "pure" object oriented language --- inconsistency with Ruby puts?

Tags: ruby, string, oop, syntax

I've often read that Ruby is a pure object oriented language since commands are typically given as messages passed to the object.

For example:

In Ruby one writes:  `"A".ord` to get the ascii code for `A`  and  `0x41.chr`  to emit the character given its ascii code.
This is in contrast to Python's:   `ord("A")` and `chr(0x41)`

So far so good --- Ruby's syntax is message passing.

**But the apparent inconsistency appears when considering the string output command:**

**Now one has: `puts str` or `puts(str)` instead of `str.puts`**

Given the pure object orientation expectation for Ruby's syntax, I would have expected the output command to be a message passed to the string object, i.e. calling a method from the string class, hence `str.puts`

Any explanations?  Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would have expected the output command to be a message passed to the string object, i.e. calling a method from the string class, hence str.puts

This is incorrect expectation, let's start with that. Why would you tell a string to `puts` itself? What would it print itself to? It knows nothing (and should know nothing) of files, I/O streams, sockets and other places you can print things to.

When you say `puts str`, it's actually seen as `self.puts str` (implicit receiver). That is, the message is sent to the current object.

Now, all objects include `Kernel` module. Therefore, **all objects** have [Kernel#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) in their lists of methods. Any object can `puts` (including current object, `self`).

As the doc says,

```
puts str
```

is translated to

```
$stdout.puts str
```

That is, by default, the implementation is delegated to standard output (print to console). If you want to print to a file or a socket, you have to invoke `puts` on an instance of file or socket classes. This is totally OO.

Comment: "This is incorrect expectation" is incorrect. Whether it should be `puts obj` or `obj.puts` depends on the perspective. There can be different opinions from different standpoints.

Comment: @sawa: what about this concrete case, though? Have you seen an OO language/lib where you tell a string to print itself? It's madness and violation of SRP.

Comment: @sawa Sergio's explanation *It should know nothing of files, I/O streams, sockets, …* is quite logical. I find no one reason why `String` class should handle or care of I/O.

Comment: Sergio, David: I added more explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Ruby isn't *entirely* OO (for example, methods are not objects), but in this case, it is. `puts` is `Kernel#puts`, which is shorthand for `$stdout.puts`. That is, you're calling the `puts` method of the `$stdout` stream and passing a string as the parameter to be output to the stream. So, when you call

```
puts "foo"
```

You're really calling:

```
$stdout.puts("foo")
```

Which is entirely consistent with OO.

Comment: Ruby is pure OO because it doesn't have methods. There are only messages (that call special object of private `Method` class). So if you look at this with this definition then it isn't nothing special that *methods* in Ruby aren't first class objects.

Comment: Method invocations are just messages, sure, but the message handlers themselves (which we call "methods") are syntactical constructs that are not directly objects themselves. You can get object handles to them, but they aren't objects (this is true for blocks, as well). This is typically what people mean when they say "almost everything in Ruby is an object".

Answer (score 2):

puts is a method on an output streams e.g.

```
$stdout.puts("this", "is", "a", "test")
```

Comment: THe other answers are more complete. Mine left for record.

Comment: (+1) Yours gives the counter-argument at a glance.  It was even better when it had a shorter example, e.g. $stdout.puts()

Comment: Thanks. I changed it match the example in the Docs ;-) IO.puts, if you are looking for it .

Answer (score 0):

Printing something to somewhere at least involves two things: what is written and where it is written to. Depending on what you focus on, there can be different implementations, even in OOP. Besides that, Ruby has a way to make a method look more like a function (i.e., not being particularly tied to a receiver as in OOP) for methods that are used all over the place. So there are at least three logical options that could be thought of for such methods like printing.

- An OOP method defined on the object to be printed
- An OOP method defined on the object where it should be printed
- A function-style method

For the second option, `IO#write` is one example; The receiver is the destination of writing.

The `puts` without an explicit receiver is actually `Kernel#puts`, and takes neither of the two as the arguments; it is an example of the third option; you are correct to point out that this is not so OOP, but Matz especially provided the `Kernel` module to be able to do things like this: a function-style method.

The first option is what you are expecting; it is nothing wrong. It happens that there is no well known method of this type, but it was proposed in the Ruby core by one of the developers, but unfortunately, it did not make it. Actually, I felt the same thing as you, and have something similar in my personal library called `Object#intercept`. A simplified version is this:

```
class Object
  def intercept
    tap{|x| p x}
  end
end

:foo.intercept # => :foo
```

You can replace `p` with `puts` if you want.

Comment: If `IO#write` corresponds to your second definition, then surely `IO#puts` does as well, doesn't it? And `$stdout` is an instance of `IO`, so if `puts` is actually syntactic sugar for `$stdout.puts`, why does `puts` fall into another category?

Comment: @user846250 Note that I wrote "`puts` without an explicit receiver", which is `Kernel#puts`. That is an entirely different thing from `$stdout.puts`, or `IO#puts`. Read more carefully.

Comment: Ok, I read more carefully and I think the disagreement stems from your definitions themselves. It seems to me that the second one (at least) is too restrictive. For instance in the case of a system logger, you would say that I'm not doing OOP because I'm calling, say `Logger.error("msg")` and it does not describe where the error message is printed to.

Comment: I would say `Logger.error("msg")` is the third type. Here, `Logger` is only working as a namespace. If you can define an instance of `Logger` and can do `Logger#error`, then that would be the second type.